# Django, Aldryn - how to show a list of categories available

Tags: python, django, divio

I am using Django for a project.

I need to be able to pull out the possible categories available.

```
{% for category in article.categories.all %}
   {{ category.name }} {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

so I can use this on an article page to see what category it is associated with. But how do I pull out the available categories to show as a list.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The articles have been assigned catergories -- that snippet of code I've shown - lists the catergories associated with a particular article.. but I want to display ALL available catergory options

Comment: I would be expecting something like..   {% for category in categories.all %}
   {{ category.name }} {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}  --- lists ALL possible catergories any article could have

Comment: When I put this on the template -- {{Category.objects.all}}  -- nothing is rendered?

Comment: I would have thought it be possible to pick it up from some variable floating around in the view. -- Not too sure where to do this or push it back into the template

Comment: Trying to hook into the aldryn_newsblog module

Comment: https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog/blob/master/aldryn_newsblog/templates/aldryn_newsblog/plugins/categories.html

Comment: "you need to add the categories plugin to your website as shown here:
http://d.pr/v/1e4Ib
"

Comment: I need to resolve this problem today

Comment: Where did you find this piece of code?

Comment: I can't remember now man - a mixture of what was on the github module

Comment: Have you ever tried displaying Tags? Your code helped me with Categories but i have yet to get the tags to display.

Comment: I can't remember now - but I think part of the bug was to include some part of the tag code - I think this is where I tried to get access to the tags